# How do I privately direct global users to API/service in their data locality?

Tags: authentication, api

If I have a common login service (login.example.com) under agreement that user information will not leave their environment. I would like to find a way to log the users in when they use a new client app, without having them select their environment. I hope for something better than having them round robin through all the environments till one lets them in.

I have two ideas:

- take hkdf of username and password. As those are known to both user and the backends, I can maintain a map of hash-> environment at login.example.com and use it without disclosing details about the users, save for the IP address.
- some multiparty computation

Is there another approach I should explore?

Comment: What do you mean by "privately direct"? Private from whom? I'm not seeing a security issue here, but just a normal programming question.

Comment: I want to direct user to their own region/environment without disclosing information about the user to any other region/environment. For example, if we a lookup service hosted in the US, auth+some profile+service logs information will be stored in the US. We we anycast, auth, logs, etc, about users will be spread across the nodes (globally). I want user information, including auth and any auth and post auth logs, to stay within the environment that stores their data.